# AngularJS setting Headers for each request

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting a header like this in Angular in the app.run()

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Test'] = 'Foobar';
```

But I can't find the "Test" request parameter on the server. What's wrong?

Comment: Why you are not setting headers like: `$http({ 'url':...... , 'method': ..... , 'header': .......})`

Answer (score 2):

use $httpProvider instead. like this

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['test'] = 'Foobar'
```

Don't forget to inject it into your function

Comment: And be sure to do it in a config block instead of a run block.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you want to put it within the app.config()